# check differences before and after merge

Tags: git

I have merged `master` branch into my local `release` branch.

Command `git log` shows me the commit hash of this merge:

```
commit a9d00h90a...
Merge 'origin/master' into release
```

Now, I want to see the differences before & after this merge. What is the git command I should run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `git diff a1b2c3d^1 a1b2c3d`

Replace the commit hash with yours. This would display pretty much your before/after comparison.

Comment: abc123^1 is "the commit before abc123", ^2 would be two commits before.

Comment: Indeed; it reffers the first parent, second parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
git show a9d00h90a
```

would show that commit and what changes it introduced

[manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show), and thit outtake

> For commits it shows the log message and textual diff. It also presents the merge commit in a special format as produced by git diff-tree --cc.

Comment: Why the down vote? This gives almost exactly the same output as the accepted answer and in a shorter way.